# How to create a key value array from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with the same number of elements which maps 1:1

```
const array1 = [1, 3, 2]
const array2 = [U2, U1, U3]
```

How can I generate a new array (or map) from array1 & array2 and have something like this ?

```
const result = [[1, U1], [2, U2], [3, U3]]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your desired result?

Comment: What is the logic - how are the 2 arrays mapped / related (order) ?

Comment: The dupe is about creating an object, not a 2d-array.

Comment: Making an array is even easier: `const array1 = [1, 3, 2];
const array2 = ["U2", "U1", "U3"];
const result = array1.map(function(item,i) {
  return [item,array2[i]];
})
console.log(result);`

Comment: the duplicate target targets an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Updated the dupe list

Comment: And does U1,2,3 actually have 1,2,3 in the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `Array.forEach()`. Before that you can sort the `array1` array and then get the corresponding value from `array2` prefixed with `U` to get the desired output:

```js
const array1 = [1, 3, 2];
const array2 = ['U2', 'U1', 'U3'];
const result = [];
array1.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
})
array1.forEach((elem, index) => result.push([elem, array2[array2.indexOf('U'+elem)]]));
console.log(result);
```

If the prefix is not always `U` then this can be used:

```js
const array1 = [1, 3, 2];
const array2 = ['U2', 'U1', 'U3'];
const result = [];
array1.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
})
array1.forEach((elem) => {
  var array2Val = array2.find(val => val.indexOf(elem) !== -1);
  result.push([elem, array2Val]);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Output is not same as OP's expected result.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think this is a dup as the OP's output is ascending based on the numeric values of `array1`. The dup question does not have that.

Comment: Your code will only work if U1 has a suffix of the same number. What if the arrays were `["One","Three","Two"]` and `["This is the first item","This is the third item","This is the second item"]`

Comment: @mplungjan OP needs to mention that

Comment: @mplungjan I have however updated the answer to tackle that and I believe OP will not have anything like the example array you have specified in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You could group the arrays by the numerical value of each item.

```js
var array1 = [1, 3, 2],
    array2 = ['U2', 'U1', 'U3'],
    result = Object.values([array1, array2].reduce(
        (o, a) => {
            a.forEach(v => {
                var k = v.toString().match(/\d+$/)[0];
                (o[k] = o[k] || []).push(v);
            });
            return o;
        },
        Object.create(null)
    ));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Output is not same as OP's expected result.

Comment: Great. It is working now. PS: I am not the one who downvoted.